# Unable to filter values in a DataFrame. NaN's in the output

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following one-column `DataFrame`, `df`:

```
timestamp                           values
2014-10-06 18:00:37.400000-04:00  0.000000    
2014-10-06 18:00:39.600000-04:00  0.000000    
2014-10-06 18:00:41.800000-04:00  2.683493    
2014-10-06 18:00:44-04:00         1.199321
```

When I do `df[df>0]` I get:

```
timestamp                           values
2014-10-06 18:00:37.400000-04:00 NaN          
2014-10-06 18:00:39.600000-04:00 NaN          
2014-10-06 18:00:41.800000-04:00  2.683493    
2014-10-06 18:00:44-04:00         1.199321
```

while I would expect to only get:

```
timestamp                           values
2014-10-06 18:00:41.800000-04:00  2.683493    
2014-10-06 18:00:44-04:00         1.199321
```

Is this expected? I know I can apply `dropna()`on this output, but isn't the above already supposed to filter out the values I ask for? (it typically works on dataframes wihtout having to call `dropna`)

Comment: `.dropna(how="any")`?

Comment: What version of pandas do you have? Can you make a fully reproducible example? The output you expect is indeed what it should be.

Comment: Ah, you don't have a *series*, but a *dataframe*. In that case indeed the output is logical, and the answer of @Primer is the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ts[ts['values']>0]` should produce the output you are looking for.

Don't know why but to have the output without NaN you need to specify column(s).
I didn't find a way to get rid of NaNs when filtering on the whole dataframe except for `.dropna()`